does variable assignment escape order of operations in c?
My understanding is that the order of operations happens left to right in c, unless there's an operation that takes precedent (like multiplication happens before addition).
int i = 3 * 2 + 4;
//i == 10

If parentheses are used, the expression in the parentheses takes precedent.
int i = (expression1) + (expression2);
//i is equal to the sum of expression1 and expression2

This is fairly obvious and straightforward
In c, the expression of setting the value of a variable can also be used as an expression
int i;
int j = (i = 5) * 2;
//i == 5 and j == 10

For some reason this breaks the order of operations.
int i;
int j = (i = 5) + (i = 6);
//why is j == 12? shouldn't it be 11?


Pretty sure that's undefined behavior due to modifying the same variable multiple times in a sequence point.

"My understanding is that the order of operations happens left to right in c,"
That's incorrect. That is the parser associativity which (with precedence) decides how the linear string of token is translated into an expression tree.
But the order of evaluation, i.e. the order in which the branches of this tree are evaluated, is generally unspecified except for specific situations. In particular + doesn't have any rule specifying the order of evaluation of its operands. (And even the parser associativity is not always left-to-right depending on operator. Sometimes it is right-to-left.)

The linked duplicate is about increment rather than assignment, but the same logic applies to any side effect on a variable.

Both associativity and precedence are defined by the standard; the order of evaluation is not.  There are some constraints, but "order of operations happens left to right in C" is certainly not correct.  See, for instance, C Operator Precedence — and a multitude of other online references.
